# overlay grid on top of pack

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to lay a grid on top of a pack? I ask this because I am trying to make an interactive map. I want a background image to take up the entire window and then place buttons on top of it in specific locations. The grid makes it is easy to place the buttons where they need to go, but I cannot get the background image to work properly unless I use a pack. Then I cannot easily place the buttons where I would like for them to go (they need to go over the top of specific places on a map i.e. buildings)

Comment: You can't mix widget layout managers in the one container. You may be able to get the effect you want by putting your background image onto a Canvas, and then [laying the buttons out on the Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method).

Comment: No, but you can layout using `place` on top of `pack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really the best way of doing it, and it has its drawbacks, but:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
with open ('map.jpg', mode='rb') as imfile:
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imfile))

bg = tk.Label(root, image=im)
bg.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=10, sticky='nesw')

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Label")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nesw')

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky='nesw')
root.mainloop()
```

the biggest issue with this is that widgets like labels won't be transparent and show the map underneath, see image:
[image: window view]

the best approach if you need transparency would be to use a canvas.

Comment: I was able to lay a place on top of a grid. That seemed very easy for me and might achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

"overlay a grid on top of pack" makes no sense. Tkinter has neither a grid nor a pack object. `grid` and `pack` are functions.

As functions, you can not use them both to manage widgets that have a common parent.

Since your goal is to have a background image, the simplest solution is to use a label rather than a frame. You can call `grid` to arrange widgets inside a label in exactly the same way that you arrange widgets inside a frame. The benefit of using a label is that you can give it an image.

Another option would be to continue to use your frame, and then use `place` to add your background image to the frame. `place` does not share the same limitation as `grid` and `pack` since it doesn't affect the geometry of the parent widget.